# Django deployment best practices

Tags: python, django, deployment

Safaribooksonline.com has a video [1] from Jacob Kaplan-Moss about how to deploy a Django app. This video is from 2010. It refers to a site [2] that has a list of many relevant aspects.
Now the workshop mentions things like virtual machines, vagrant (as deployment environments) or Fabric and other tools for deployment automation.

I was wondering how much has changed since then. I can think of Docker replacing Vagrant. Or Heroku or AWS instead of renting a dedicated physical server for deployment (or virtual machines). Or using Ansible or Chef / Puppet instead of Capistrano or Fabric.

But what else has changed? What is still relevant? What is done differently? What is the state of the art in 2017 for deploying a production ready Django app.

Can anybody point me to good blogs / books / tutorials?

---

[1] "Django deployment workshop", https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/django-deployment-workshop/9781449396442/

[2] "infrastructure of modern websites", https://randomfoo.net/2009/01/28/infrastructure-for-modern-web-sites

Comment: Docker has definitely replaced Vagrant in local dev at least. I think this really depends on scale and purpose. Are we also including things like awsgi vs uwsgi?

Comment: Could not use Docker on a Mac productively. Still feel more comfortable deploying to a VM. (Never made the transition to deploying to Azure or AWS.) - Haven't used Django Channels so far.

Comment: If you ask the "enterprise"-people, they would probably tell you to use kubernetes or similar. That will involve docker. Send logs to a logging service. Use uwsgi. Make uwsgi serve static files or use cdn.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the answer to this question will be extremely opinionated and defining best practices in ever-changing devops area can be challenging. Something is a best practice one day, and tomorrow someone makes a blog post about that being god awful and obsolete.

There are numerous ways to do deployment, but it all comes down to what do you need, how much do you want to automate and what level of customization is required.

- For instance, at my current place we use CircleCI, Heroku, Sentry and
  Rollbar.
- One of my previous clients (three months ago) wanted us to use
  CodePipeline which includes CodeCommit, CodeBuild, CodeDeploy for
  AWS.
- Recently I also worked on a project involving Docker and flexible
  environment from Google App Engine.
- For my personal projects I simply use Fabric and Heroku, but I'd really like to try the new CodeStar or whatever the name is on AWS.

Define what you want, how you want to customize it and simply do it. If something does not work out, just change it. Things are becoming easier to do and replacing one item in your pipeline can occur in matter of minutes and not days/weeks as it did. Nowadays every provider has support for Docker and CI, one way or the other.

YMMV.